# Fluid mechanics - rotating Bucket - euler fluid - symmetries

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Rotating Bucket, gravity, euler fluid. E.g faber ch 2 or landau, if we start from the full 3 d equations in cylindrical coördinaties, we have symmetry over the azimuthal angle, but why is there symmetry for radius and z ? I.e why pressure and speed should not depend on r and z ?
For example, I may have vortex in z and r, e.g what would happen at a very high speed / high Reynolds number?
The most simple solution is the one with symmetry clear but other configurations with vortices are allowed by the equations ?

Same line of questions is for the symmetry of the angular / radial speed, the most simple configuration is the one with constant angular speed  (I.e. As a rigid body) but are configurations with different angular speeds allowed ? The pressure profile will also vary, but why not a speed that goes with $r^2$ or anything else ?

Thanks

Comment: PS: there are the constraints from the boundaries clear, but these constraints are not propagated strictly through the fluid, given the fact there is no viscosity. there are areas of the fluid that can have  various speed profiles. This is a question substantially about the uniqueness of the solution.